# Concatenating JS bundles from JSON files with gulp

Tags: node.js, json, gulp, npm-scripts

In case of gulp and node I am more a user than a developer. So I hope to find some advide here.

I am having several JSON files. Each one defines a bundle of JS files. I want to use gulp or an npm script to loop over the JSON files and concatenate the files listed inside to a JS file.

Example JSON file:

```
{
    "lib": [
        "choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"
    ],
    "src": [
        "base.js",
        "address.js"
    ]
}
```

The resulting list of files to concatenate should look like this:

```js
[
    './node_modules/choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js',
    './assets/js/src/base.js',
    './assets/js/src/address.js'
]
```

The resulting JS file should be stored in './dist/js/' and be named like original JSON file, except the extension of cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some techniques in the following that you will find useful.  Particularly `glob.sync`, see [glob documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const glob = require("glob");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const path = require("path");

// returns an array, assumes files are named "_something.json"
const jsonFiles = glob.sync("assets/js/_*.json");


function concatJSONfiles(done) {

  jsonFiles.forEach(jsonFile => {
    let array2Concat = [];

    const concatName = path.format({
      name: path.basename(jsonFile, ".json"),
      ext: ".js"
    });
    // concatName = "_bundle1.js", "_bumdle2.js", etc.

    const thisFile = require(path.join(__dirname, jsonFile));  // get and parse each _bundle<n>.json

    // build the array for gulp.src from each key in the _bundle.json's
    // if more than the two specified keys ("lib" and "src") just loop through them all
    // with the array returned from Objeect.keys(thisFile);

    thisFile.lib.forEach(item => array2Concat.push(path.join(".", "node_modules", item)));
    thisFile.src.forEach(item => array2Concat.push(path.join(".", "assets", "js", item)));

    return gulp.src(array2Concat)
      .pipe(concat(concatName))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));    
  });
  done();
};

module.exports.concat = concatJSONfiles;
```

I was using this folder structure:

```
├── assets
|  └── js
|     ├── address1.js
|     ├── address2.js
|     ├── base1.js
|     ├── base2.js
|     ├── _bundle1.json
|     └── _bundle2.json
├── gulpfile.js
└── node_modules
   └── choices.js
      └── public
         └── assets
            └── scripts
               └── choices.min.js
```

and producing:

```
├── dist
|  └── js
|     ├── _bundle1.js
|     └── _bundle2.js
```

Comment: This looks more professional than my approach. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

So I had to figure it out myself, but I think it's definitively not the best solution.

First of all I had no idea how to iterate over the JSON files and use their content, so I needed to use a single bundle JSON file.

```
{
    "address": {
        "lib": [
            "choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"
        ],
        "src": [
            "base.js",
            "address.js"
        ]
    },
    "foobar": {
        "src": [
            "base.js",
            "foobar.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

With that in place I can iterate the keys and add the paths to the file names of each section, create an array an hand it to gulp-concat.

```js
const master = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( './package.json' ) );
const jsBundles = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( './assets/js/_bundles.json' ) );

…

function prepareBundle( key )
{
    var result = [];
    if ( typeof( jsBundles[ key ].lib ) !== 'undefined' )
    {
        for ( var i in jsBundles[ key ].lib)
        {
            result.push( './node_modules/' + jsBundles[ key ].lib[ i ] );
        }
    }

    if ( typeof( jsBundles[ key ].src ) !== 'undefined' )
    {
        for ( var i in jsBundles[ key ].src)
        {
            result.push(  master.config.jsSrc + jsBundles[ key ].src[ i ] );
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function createBundle( files, filename )
{
    return src( files )
        .pipe( concat( filename + '.js' ) )
        .pipe( dest( master.config.jsDist ) );
}

function javascripts( done )
{
    for ( var key in jsBundles )
    {
        ( function( key )
        {
            var files = prepareBundle( key );
            process.stdout.write( 'creating bundle: ' + key + '\n' );
            createBundle( files, key );
        })( key );
    }
    done();
}
```

Comment: You can just `require` a `.json` file in _node.js_ instead of `fs.readFileSync`. For instance: `const master = require( './package.json' );` - it also parses the content, so there's no need to `JSON.parse` either.